# Embedding JAR file into HTML?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, installation

I have a Runnable jar file, is there anyway to embed it into html so people dont have to download my game to play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Applet is what you want...put the following inside your html..

```
<APPLET ARCHIVE="yourfile.jar" CODE="yourApplet.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200>
 </APPLET>
```

Of course for this, your jar file must contain `yourApplet.class`

Comment: also beware the inner classes, most hostings don't play nicely with paths that contain $ in them.

Comment: @MahdeTo  I don't understand the point of your comment. 1) The code attribute will never have a $ character in it. 2) It makes no sense to put a $ symbol in the name of the Jar 3) The JRE and every server I have ever tried are just fine at negotiating the loading of loose class files with $ in the name.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's simply a go easy with innerclasses, some web hostings have problems loading them, (yahoo geocities had that a couple of years ago).

Comment: So my program's jar file is called flncrst.jar, and I have about 10 different class, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can (install &) launch Java rich client apps. (e.g. Swing, SWT, AWT) from a link on a web page.

Note that both web-start & converting the app. to an applet mentioned by other people, would effectively download the Jar to the users computer, it's just that it is 'invisible' to them (unless it is 60+ megabytes - in which case the time will be noticed).

As an aside, speaking as someone with extensive experience of both applets and JWS, I *strongly* recommend to avoid applets for this one.  Use JWS.  It is easier, and no conversion of the 'main' class is required. Either way, the Jar **will** end up needing to be digitally signed.