# How to use embed or object in html5?

Tags: html, object, applet, embed

I know that *`<Applet>`* does not work in HTML5 but in 4.1, but how do i use *`<embed>`* or *`<object>`* becose if i use *`<embed src=SOMETHING.jar>`* or *`<object width="400" height="400" data="SOMETHING.jar"></object>`* it just downloads *SOMETHING.jar*.

How can i just (dis)play it?

Comment: I will proppebly not be on when I get an answer(Blame School).

Comment: Browsers don't play Java applets at all any more, regardless of the element you use.

Comment: Can you help this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562092/embedding-jar-file-into-html