# Running A Jar In Browser

Tags: java, web-applications, jar

I need to run a jar inside a web app ( well in html file). I know there is applet , but i have only a jar which i need to run in html. 
How to do that ?  some advice , links or anything useful is highly appreciated. I have looking for it, may be not looking for it in right way(?)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding JAR file into HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562092/embedding-jar-file-into-html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: But I mentioned clearly , it is a JAR

Comment: I know how to run  applet

Comment: Err, applets are classes, and classes are bundled in jar files. So, if you know how to run an applet, that shouldn't be a problem. Note however that applets are de facto dead for years, and officially dead now. Browsers don't run them anymore. Java doesn't run in browsers anymore.

Comment: @itsMe You should probably explain what are you trying to achieve with that jar. Because running jar in html makes not sense - what it will do if it is not applet? Using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) you could run jar in browser but that is only because it is compiled into javascript including some client UI code.